# I need some contracts about the gas vulnerability

Tags: gas, contract-debugging, out-of-gas

I am working on detecting gas-related vulnerabilities in smart contracts, out of gas caused by excessive iteration and  malicious loops , etc.
If you have such contracts, please provide them to me, many thanks!

Comment: Can you send the contract?

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you have a `for` loop going through array of user addresses.

If anyone can add an address there, soon the array is going to get too large (it will cost too much gas).

Once the gas price is above block-gas limit, your code will no longer be functional.

In short,  you should try to avoid loops in solidity.

Comment: yes,This is one of those situations where we are looking for realistic contracts about out-of-gas and collecting them, so some proponents are needed to provide these examples

Comment: So you are looking for real contracts that have been deployed by devs, but it turned out they had this design flaw?

Comment: To be precise, we are looking for contracts that are vulnerable and focused on gas-related vulnerabilities. We need the actual contract code